# Split Firstname and Lastname

Tags: python, split

So, I've found this topic: [Separate first, middle and last names (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678132/separate-first-middle-and-last-names-python), and I tried to adapt the code to my needs on OpenERP.

I've currently this:

```
class get_the_name(object):
            def __init__(self, fullname):
                self.full = fullname
                s = self.full.split()

                try:
                    self.first = " ".join(s[:2]) if len(s[0]) == 1 else s[0]
                    s = s[len(self.first.split()):]

                    self.middle = " ".join(s[:2]) if len(s[0]) == 1 else s[0]
                    s = s[len(self.middle.split()):]

                    self.last = " ".join(s[:2]) if len(s[0]) == 1 else s[0]
                finally:
                    pass
class class_A(osv.osv):

    _name = 'classA.classA'
    _rec_name = 'name_of'
    _columns = {
        'name_of':fields.char('Name:', size = 10),
            'description_':fields.char('Description:', size = 10),
            'first_last':fields.function(get_the_name("Just testing this").first, method = True, string = "Split Name", type = "char", size = 50),
    }
class_A()
```

Although this is giving me the error message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'func_name'

Even if this had word, I don't want this way. Instead of the function be:

```
'first_last':fields.function(get_the_name("Just testing this").first, method = True, string = "Split Name", type = "char", size = 50),
```

I would like it to be:

```
'first_last':fields.function(get_the_name(name_of).first, method = True, string = "Split Name", type = "char", size = 50),
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The problem is you are supposed to pass a function object, but you pass a string value. Why do you use a class anyway?

Comment: I just solved the problem: http://pastebin.com/VBr9qFRz